# Stenciljs: Cannot find another component

Tags: jsx, stenciljs, stencil-component, stencil-compiler

I have created a new project in Stenciljs, but I have a problem using the components created in that project.

```js
import { Component, h, Prop } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
    tag: 'fd-story',
    styleUrl: './story.css',
    shadow: true
})
export class Story {

    @Prop() name = '';

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="label">
                <span>{this.name}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I need to use this component in another container component (Carousel), but I have the following problem:
[image]

As a solution to this problem, VSCode tells me that I can import that component, but when I do, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Class constructor Story cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I am working on Windows 10. Has anyone happened? I appreciate your comments.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had a beginner's mistake. I wasn't calling the component the right way:

```html
 <Story
    visited={true}
    name='Comida 1'
    image='https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2a/45/af/2a45af7fa0c4347526f90ecc56e5764e.jpg'
 />
```

I should have called it that.

```html
 <fd-story
    visited={true}
    name='Comida 1'
    image='https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2a/45/af/2a45af7fa0c4347526f90ecc56e5764e.jpg'
 />
```

I was invoking the Class of the component, but I needed to call the tag name (fd-story). I hope someone else serves it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'tag' from below code as your tag name.

```
@Component({
    tag: 'fd-story',
    styleUrl: './story.css',
    shadow: true })
```

so here you should use 'fd-story' instead of 'story'